# Nil values are returned if accessing the yaml file from a method

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a Ruby class with methods (used as static) and in one of them I have some code that reads a YAML file and retrieves what information is needed. For some reason the code from the methods retrieves nil. If I put the code from the method in a .rb file and run it, it works OK.
This is my class

```
require 'yaml'

class MyClass
  def self.get_values(param1, param2)
     f = YAML.load_file("za_file")
     return f[param1][param2] 
  end
end

puts MyClass.get_values('val1','val2')
```

The next code works with no problems.

```
require 'yaml'

f = YAML.load_file("za_file")
puts f['val1']['val2']
```

The yaml file is configured this way:

```
val1:
  val2: "some string"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Imposibru. what will you get with `puts f.inspect` instead of return statement in the class?

Comment: It retrieves the entire content of the yaml file. I saw now that the problem is when I add the second parameter f['val1']['val2']. I have edited the post and added how I have wrote the yaml file.

Comment: What do you get with `f['val1']`. Is it hash?

Comment: Yes. {"val1"=>{"val2"=>"some string"}

Comment: Ah, use `YAML.load_file`, not `YAML.load`

Comment: Aw.. sorry about this, I had it 'load_file' all along. I will modify my post.

Comment: Both snippets (w/class and plain) work fine for me. I bet you omit some meaningful details.

Comment: Well, for me this is still not working. It might be just a stupid mistake.. but until I manage to find it continues to be a problem. Continuing searching... thanks for the help :).